# How do I specify a mix of an expression and a string as a class for an ember component?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to do something like this

```
{{#my-custom-component class="some-class-name {{dynamicProperty}}" }}
```

But this is literally rendering `some-class-name {{dynamicProperty}}` as the classname, rather than the value it represents.

Comment: By reading the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/components/defining-a-component/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [concat](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/concat?anchor=concat) helper:

```
{{#my-custom-component class=(concat 'some-class-name' dynamicProperty) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're already inside an expression, so you'll want to leave off the `{{` - and also the quotes in this case - because it isn't a string. : )

```
<div class='{{exampleClass}}'>message in template</div>

{{!-- vs --}}

{{#example-component class=exampleClass}}message in component{{/example-component}}
```

This is your components 'controller' basically:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'section',
  classNames: ['class-from-component-controller'],
});
```

The scope of your template (of the same name) uses this controller as it's 'memory' in a way. - so, you can use the built in property 'classNames' array - in the controller / or the template.

```
{{#example-component class='strong-voice' classNames=exampleClass}}
    message in component
{{/example-component}}
```

[twiddle example](https://ember-twiddle.com/c933e81129d7b3da39db7eac1ac31e01?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Comment: ugh I just realized why I'm struggling with this, I'm trying to mix a string with the expression, I've updated my question (I like your answer though)

Comment: Note that `classNames` is an array. + if you like an answer / you should vote it up. If the answer solves your question, you should also mark it as correct. Good luck!